# Bitbucket Pipeline - docker compose error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket-pipelines

I am having trouble running docker compose in bitbucket pipeline. I have no issue running the command locally.

```
image: node:16

options:
  docker: true

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3072

pipelines:
  default:
.
.
.
            - docker compose version
            - docker compose build
            - ls
          caches:
            - node
          services:
            - docker
```

ERROR

```
+ docker compose build
listing workers for Build: failed to list workers: Unavailable: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing unable to upgrade to h2c, received 403"
```

Comment: How did you install docker-compose? What's the output of docker compose version instruction? Would you complete the code of the bitbucket-pipelines.yml? There is a whole missing fragment in your step definition!

Comment: Can you provide your docker-compose file?